# Spatial join for adjacent polygons with same attributes

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, topology

I am working with QGIS 3.4.5. I have a map of soil types (~ 100.000 polygons) and I'm trying to find the best way to make a spatial join with ~5000 point features with several numerical characteristics of soil samples. So, most soil types polygons do not have any point sample within it. At the end of this task, I need to have a polygon shapefile and all features should have informations on joined from the attribute table of the point features file but I'm not sure how to do that.

I already did a simple spatial join to get a summary of the point attributes that were inside the soil types. On the next step, for polygons without any point inside (and no numerical information on attributes table after the spatial join) I am trying to find a way to make a test to check if a polygon "X" with data has the same attribute (i.e. levels of soil classification) than polygon "Y" (no data) considering also if they are adjacents. In case of the attributes are the same, the polygon "Y" will get the same attributes of polygon "X".

Any ideas on how to do this in a proper way using QGIS tools?

Comment: You could use the nearest neighbor plugin to do a nearest-neighbor join. Then use the field calculator and a conditional statement to copy the joined fields into the original numerical characteristic fields if the two soil types match.